# what is the data type that i want to use when merging Array when i merge String array and Integer Array into merge Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I have an String Array and Integer Array,

```
String[] strArray={"a","b","c"};
Integer[] intArray={1,2,3};
```

I want two merge them into another array.What is the data type of merge Array?and how i implement merge Array?

Comment: You have to convert the Integer array to string array then merge them to String array.

Comment: You can use Maps in Java. Here you can assign String array as key and Integer array as value.

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Why do you need to mix those two arrays?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, String and Integer both are inherited from Object. So you can use Object type to define a general array.

```
    String[] strArray = { "a", "b", "c" };
    Integer[] intArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
    Object[] arr = new Object[strArray.length + intArray.length];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        arr[j++] = strArray[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        arr[j++] = intArray[i];
    }
```

Comment: Just not good... If now I add another element, will be a what? String? Integer? Object like a Cat or maybe a House? And after that, I want to do something with all that elements, maybe take the first... And what will it be?

Comment: Damain: don't think too far. It's enough to resolve his question.

Comment: @DamianLattenero it's the best option if you really need `Integer` and `String` in the same array (note, you can't define a common interface for them). To find out the type of an element there is always `instanceof`. Of course, all that is not nice. So the question remains, why merge in the first place?

Comment: @Henry sure... It's just my instinct telling me "please don't do it!"... maybe I'm being to strict with no need to be...

Comment: @kimdung I made a little edit if you allow me, so I can remove the Dvote

Comment: @Daminan. I have read your answer. Even though I didn't explain detail my answer, but I don't think there is any problem there because String and Integer both are inherited from Object. Meanwhile, a parent array can be used to containing two children types.

Comment: Everything inherits from Object, that's what  makes a lot of noise. But, don't worry, your answer solves the OP question, congrats! It seems he needed to do that, and that's it ^^

Comment: @Damian, it's good to discuss with you. You can give me your solution here. Then we can continue to discuss it.

Comment: @kimdung thanks haha, but I am so sorry, because I can give my solution because of the lack of information of the problem :(, that's why I asked to the OP why he is doing that... If I knew, I could think another way, with classes and  interfaces. But I just can't because I don't know what he will do with the mixed array, each element, what behavior it willl have, and so on. So, your answer just hit the target! Plus one for that so... my mistake

Comment: @DamianLattenero Haha, I have to plus one this just for the comments. My instinct was the same as yours Damian.

Answer (score 2):

> The first instinct would be to me:

In Java you just can have one Type for container, if you want to mix two types, you have to create some abstraction, like an Interface, or create another way to relate your String with your Integer.

> But

consider the @kimdung answer if you *just want to mix the two arrays and just this*, and if you don't care anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use object type array, as in your case you are using integer wrapper object and string, which can be merge as object in java

Answer (score 0):

Make a Sting array and merge both into that array, you will have to convert Integer to String while merging and the converse when you are retrieving for any purpose

```
for(int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++) {
     mergerArray[i] = String.value(intArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.arraycopy();`

```
String[] strArray={"a","b","c"};
Integer[] intArray={1,2,3};
Object[] objArray = new Object[strArray.length + intArray.length];

System.arraycopy( strArray, 0, objArray, 0, strArray.length );
System.arraycopy( intArray, 0, objArray, strArray.length, intArray.length );
```

Rather than type `Object`, you can change to desired type like `String`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to join two arrays of difference types. But I want to recommend you to use instances java.util.ArrayList instead of array. For example you can join these two different arrays.

```
ArrayList<Character> strArr= new ArrayList<Character>();
strArr.add(new Character('a'));
strArr.add(new Character('b'));
strArr.add(new Character('c'));
ArrayList<Character> intArr= new ArrayList<Character>();
intArr.add(new Character('1'));
intArr.add(new Character('2'));
intArr.add(new Character('3'));
//merge two arrays
strArr.addAll(intArr);
```